# Can I have Visual Studio 2013 run a Powershell command on File Save?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2013

I have a powershell window constantly open, so that when I'm making edits to files that don't require recompile (like angular pages, Views, configs, images, etc), I can just run a command (I call it 'Sync'), and it will copy over the files I changed to my build directory, without having to do a Build.

Is it possible to have Visual Studio run that command when I do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>? The amount of time to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to the new window, run the command, then tab to the browser, seems inconsequential, but I do it dozens, if not hundreds, of times a day, and I know it would save time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of an easy way to do this completely automatically on file save, but you may be able save yourself *some* trouble by using External Tools (under Tools / External Tools).

It's possible to substitute macros for things like the full path to the current file, etc. You get a menu item under Tools, and you can assign a keyboard shortcut to it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for a Visual Studio add-in.  See this [blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingWorkspaceReloaderAVisualStudioAddInToSaveYourOpenFilesAcrossProjectReloads.aspx) by Scott Hanselman on how to write one.